# Assign Menus to Theme Locations with theme activation

Tags: menus, child-theme

A site is using "child1" named child theme. When this site switches to other child theme named "child2", their widgets are moving too but theme locations are not moving. How can i auto assign menus to theme locations on theme activation?

I found this solution from http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-assign-a-wordpress-3-menu-to-primary-location-programmatically

```
$theme = get_current_theme();
$mods = get_option("mods_$theme");
$key = key($mods['nav_menu_locations']);
$mods['nav_menu_locations'][$key] = $menu_id;
update_option("mods_$theme", $mods);
```

Is there any better wordpress way to fix this?
(Related trac topic: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18720 )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well,
I wrote a solution so writing it here:

```
/* 
 This action copies old theme's theme location saves to 
 new theme if new theme doesnt have saves before.
 */
 add_action( 'after_switch_theme',  'ajx_theme_locations_rescue' );
 function ajx_theme_locations_rescue() {
    // bug report / support: http://www.unsalkorkmaz.com/
    // We got old theme's slug name
    $old_theme = get_option( 'theme_switched' );
    // Getting old theme's settings
    $old_theme_mods = get_option("theme_mods_{$old_theme}");
    // Getting old theme's theme location settings
    $old_theme_navs = $old_theme_mods['nav_menu_locations'];
    // Getting new theme's theme location settings
    $new_theme_navs = get_theme_mod( 'nav_menu_locations' );

    // If new theme's theme location is empty (its not empty if theme was activated and set some theme locations before)
    if (!$new_theme_navs) {
        // Getting registered theme locations on new theme
        $new_theme_locations = get_registered_nav_menus();

        foreach ($new_theme_locations as $location => $description ) {
            // We setting same nav menus for each theme location 
            $new_theme_navs[$location] = $old_theme_navs[$location];
        }

        set_theme_mod( 'nav_menu_locations', $new_theme_navs );

    }
 }
```

Comment: i tried all possibilities and it seems working but please if u want to use it, try as much as possible and if its working or not, write here.

Answer (score 1):

I know you had this issue long time ago but since this site popped up with the first few, I thought to share my solution in case someone needs it.

Either in your setup file or in your general `functions.php`, update and include the following code:

```
// This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in one location.
register_nav_menu( 'primary', __( 'Primary Menu', 'theme-slug' ) );

// get 'your_custom_menu' id to assign it to the primary menu location created
$menu_header = get_term_by('name', 'your_custom_menu', 'nav_menu');
$menu_header_id = $menu_header->term_id;

// if menu not found, create a new one
if($menu_header_id == 0) {
     $menu_header_id = wp_create_nav_menu('your_custom_menu');
}

//Get all locations (including the one we just created above)
$locations = get_theme_mod('nav_menu_locations');

// set the menu to the new location and save into database
$locations['primary'] = $menu_header_id;
set_theme_mod( 'nav_menu_locations', $locations );
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.